# display none -> display using state in reactjs styled-components

Tags: reactjs

I tried to build Modal component.
My approach is changing `display: none` to `display: block` of  when state ***visible*** changed.

the  has nested tags inside given by function **buildTopicList(topicDummy)**,

but when I change props **visible** of `<TopicBox>`, the return value of `buildTopicList(topicDummy) is gone and no more contents inside````

---

For fix this things, used
`` [topicList, setTopicList] = useState(buildTopicList(topicDummy))` and replace ``
buildTopicList(topicDummy)`width`topicList```.

my question is why contents inside `<TopicBox></TopicBox>` is gone when state is changed when I use just `buildTopicList(topicDummy)` but a `{topicList}` ?

plz see the codes below.

```js
export const TopicBox = styled.div<{
  visible: boolean 
}>`
  display: ${p => p.visible ? 'initial' : 'none'};
  border: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.15);
  border-radius: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 56px;
  background-color: ${p=>p.theme.colors.white};
  max-width: 528px;
  max-height:216px;
  overflow-y: auto; 

`;
///this works
const [topicList, setTopicList ] = useState(buildTopicList(topicDummy));

const toggleTopicList = () => {
      setVisible((visible) => !visible);
    }
return
...
<TopicButton
    onClick={toggleTopicList}
>
    <Hamburger/>  
    <TopicTitle>Topic</TopicTitle>
</TopicButton>
<TopicBox
   visible={visible}
   ref={topicRef}
>
   {topicList}
</TopicBox>
```

```
//this doesn't work
const toggleTopicList = () => {
      setVisible((visible) => !visible);
    }
return
...
<TopicButton
    onClick={toggleTopicList}
>
    <Hamburger/>  
    <TopicTitle>Topic</TopicTitle>
</TopicButton>
<TopicBox
   visible={visible}
   ref={topicRef}
>
   {buildTopicList(topicDummy)}
</TopicBox>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

try it like this:

`display: ${({ visible }) => visible ? 'initial' : 'none'};`

Comment: unfortunately, display and initial wasn't problem. thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: I just applied alternative ways using useState I mention above.
but I hope the reason why just put function value doesn't work

Comment: have you tried this instead? `const toggleTopicList = () => {setVisible(!visible)}`